# Gravatar Size Via Theme Functions?

Tags: gravatar

Currently, to call comments I am simply using:

```
<?php wp_list_comments(); ?>
```

in comments.php.  This is calling up gravatars, which I would like to be able to set the size of.  How can I set the size of gravatars in my comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simple, actually:

```
wp_list_comments( 'avatar_size=80' );
```

Just change `avatar_size=80` to whatever is appropriate.

Here's a bit more information on [customizing Gravatars in WordPress](http://www.chipbennett.net/2010/09/25/custom-wordpress-gravatars-the-right-way/).

Comment: Good article.  You wouldn't know that "cb" guy by chance??

Comment: I've been told I look like him - the poor guy!